# Spring Boot Second DataSource results in Could not autowire field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to setup a Spring Boot application with two datasources. I've successfully got the first datasource working, but when I add the class to handle the second datasource, the first no longer works and results in DAO's for the first datasource not being autowired, meaning the DOAs can't be loaded in my controller.

Here's the class which sets up the first datasource.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "digital.sheppard.dao.local",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "localEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "localTransactionManager"
)
public class LocalDBConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(localDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "digital.sheppard.model.local" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("datasource.local.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("datasource.local.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.naming-strategy", env.getProperty("org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);


        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    public DataSource localDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("datasource.local.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("datasource.local.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("datasource.local.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("datasource.local.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager localTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(localEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Here's the class that attempts to setup a second datasource.

```
    @Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "digital.sheppard.dao.eclipse",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "eclipseEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "eclipseTransactionManager"
)
public class EclipseDBConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean eclipseEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(eclipseDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "digital.sheppard.model.eclipse" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("datasource.eclipse.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("datasource.eclipse.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.naming-strategy", env.getProperty("org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);


        return em;
    }

    public DataSource eclipseDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("datasource.eclipse.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("datasource.eclipse.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("datasource.eclipse.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("datasource.eclipse.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager eclipseTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(eclipseEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

It seems to me that the second datasource is overwriting the first, and as a result the application is no longer able to locate the DOA that are defined in the primary datasource.

Is there any reason why my second DataSource would stop DAO's from the first DataSource to no longer load?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working, I'm not entirely sure what the issue was. I ended up scrapping the classes and starting again.

For anyone else with a similar issue, here's my application.properties file

```
primary.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.19/ticket
primary.datasource.username = username
primary.datasource.password = password
primary.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

secondary.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.19/ticket2
secondary.datasource.username = username
secondary.datasource.password = passwprd
secondary.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

The class that defines the primary datasource, transaction manager and entity manager.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "digital.sheppard.dao.local",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "localEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "localTransactionManager"
)
public class LocalDBConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="primary.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "digital.sheppard.model.local" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager localTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(localEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

The class to define the second datasource is very similar, notice the exclusion @Primary

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "digital.sheppard.dao.eclipse",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "eclipseEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "eclipseTransactionManager"
)
public class EclipseDBConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="secondary.datasource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean eclipseEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(secondaryDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "digital.sheppard.model.eclipse" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager eclipseTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(eclipseEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

The DOA's for the primary datasource are the same as those used for the secondary datasource, except that the secondary data source defined which transaction manager to use in the @Transactional annotation.

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "eclipseTransactionManager")
@Repository
public interface Person2Dao extends CrudRepository<Person2, Integer> {

}
```